# How to send an embed located in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to send an embed from my `help.js`, triggered by the `main.js` code.
This is what I've been trying:

```js
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");


module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {
    const sayEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    my embed
    .settimestamp();
 message.channel.send(sayEmbed)
  }
};
```

But I'm always getting this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: You haven't set the Description

Comment: i set it but it still not working

Comment: Are you using discord.js V13?

Comment: yes i do using v13

Comment: Can you update your code in the question if you have made changes to it?

Comment: this is how v13 send embed btw `message.channel.send({ embeds: [sayEmbed] })`

Comment: i got this after using the embed thing
message.channel.send({ embeds: [sayEmbed] });}
                                ^

ReferenceError: sayEmbed is not defined

Comment: im using 
execute: async (client, message, args) => {
var sayEmbed = new MessageEmbed() 
  .setcolor ('RANDOM')
  .setauthor ( 'Help Panel')
  .setDescription('Some description here')
  .setfooter (`Requested by ${ message.author.tag }` )
  .addfields( ....
 )
}
message.channel.send({ embeds: [sayEmbed] });}

    });

Answer (score 0):

On Discord **v13** you need to send embeds little differently, try out:

```js
message.channel.send({embeds: [sayEmbed]});
```